# is it possible to read from a specific character in a line from a file in c++?

Tags: c++, string, fstream

Hey all so I have to get values from a text file, but the values don't stand alone they are all written as this:

Population size: 30

Is there any way in c++ that I can read from after the ':'?
I've tried using the >> operator like:

```
string pop;
inFile >> pop;
```

but off course the whitespace terminates the statement before it gets to the number and for some reason using

```
inFile.getline(pop, 20);
```

gives me loads of errors because it does not want to write directly to string for some reason..
I don't really want to use a char array because then it won't be as easy to test for the number and extract that alone from the string.
So is there anyway I can use the getline function with a string?
And is it possible to read from after the ':' character?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string fname;
    cin >> fname;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(fname.c_str()); 
    string pop1;
    getline(inFile,pop1);
    cout << pop1;
    return 0;
}
```

ok so here is my code with the new getline, but it still outputs nothing. it does correctly open the text file and it works with a char array

Comment: There is a version of `getline` for `std::string` that is not a member of input streams: `std::getline(inFile, pop)`.

Comment: thanks for the help, this statements doesn't cause any errors but it doesn't output anything when I use cout << pop;

Comment: The only reason that would fail is if 1) You input the wrong filename (thus the file failed to open correctly) 2) The file was empty 3) The first line in the file is blank. Add error checking to make sure the file opens. Then print every line in the file with: `while(std::getline(inFile, pop1)) { std::cout << "Line:  " << pop1 << "\n";}`

Answer (score 4):

You are probably best to read the whole line then manipulate the string :-

```
std::string line;
std::getline(inFile, line);
line = line.substr(19);  // Get character 20 onwards...
```

You are probably better too looking for the colon :-

```
size_t pos = line.find(":");
if (pos != string::npos)
{
    line = line.substr(pos + 1);
}
```

Or something similar

Once you've done that you might want to feed it back into a stringstream so you can read ints and stuff?

```
int population;
std::istringstream ss(line);
ss >> population;
```

Obviously this all depends on what you want to do with the data

Comment: thanks yeah that was what i was thinking. so for a string you use getline(inFile, line) instead of the inFile.getline(pop, 20);? cool

Comment: ok so when i use this code there are no errors but if i cout << line; it doesn't show anything

Comment: No. The whole point of the stream operators is to avoid string manipulation like this. yes read the line in one go but use a stringstream to parse the data

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your data is in the form

```
 <Key>:<Value>
```

One per line. Then I would do this:

```
std::string line;
while(std::getline(inFile, line))
{
    std::stringstream  linestream(line);

    std::string key;
    int         value;

    if (std::getline(linestream, key, ':') >> value)
    {
        // Got a key/value pair
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks to be whitespace between the colon and the value, but I think that's OK.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Streams will correctly handle extra white-space after the colon. So not a problem.

Comment: thanks the "key" part is irrelevant, i only need the numbers because they go into a GA. What is really killing me is that this getline(inFile, line) is not storing anything inside my string

Comment: @user1763722: That's probably because you have an empty line on your input. This is usually caused by mixing calls to std::getline() and `operator>>`. But to really answer that question you need to ask the question properly. Provide the code you are using (it must be compilable) with the input. Then we can tell you exactly why it is failing.

Comment: @user1763722: There also seems to be some confusion on which version of getline you are using. Your question indicates `stream.getline()` but your comments seem to indicate `std::getline()` these are two completely different functions.

Comment: int main()
    {
     string fname;
     cin >> fname;
     ifstream inFile;
     inFile.open(fname.c_str()); 
     string pop1;
    getline(inFile,pop1);
    cout << pop1;
    return 0;
    }