# Read Specific Entry From Text File

Tags: c++, text, line, fstream

> This is the text file named "TextFile.txt"

```
Stat    Rain
1       16
2       34
3       24
4       23
5       21
6       19
7       17
8       35
9       27
```

And here is my c++ code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
char Station[9];
char Rainfall[9];
int i;
int j;
int s[23];
double r[23];
main()
{
    ifstream Read;
    Read.open("TextFile.txt");
    Read>>Station;//I don't want this
    Read>>Rainfall;//I have no choice then I just assign these two variables
    i=0;
    while(!Read.eof())//This is the only I want
    {
        i++;
        Read>>s[i]>>r[i];
    }
    Read.close();
    for(j=1;j<i;j++)
    {
        cout<<s[j]<<"\t"<<r[j]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want only the data. So how can I skip the first line and read the second line immediately? If possible, how can I read only second column without wasting of time to read the first column?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209650/is-it-possible-to-read-from-a-specific-character-in-a-line-from-a-file-in-c?rq=1

may be this could help you!!

Comment: @baibhavk Hmmm, it is not my desire. In my text file, the first two entries are titles. I want to skip them and read only the data.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getLine()` for reading first line and then start to read second line .. It the most possible choice I think.

You can do such things ;

```
ifstream stream("TextFile.txt");
string dummyLine;
getline( stream, dummyLine );
/*    
   Here you can read your values 
*/
while (stream)
```

Comment: Did you mean start read from the first line? The first line is the title as mentioned from the beginning. I want to skip it and read only the data bellow the titles ahead.

Comment: I understand you just read first line with getline() and then you can read your real data

and also read line by line dont use eof() .